# TextView with marquee is not working

Tags: android, textview, marquee

Despite I managed to make a `marquee TextView` as I followed a tutorial, and it's working correctly, when I tried to make another `TextView` in a different activity as `marquee` it did not work. I followed the same step accurately but with no avail. what do you think I am missing?

***Update***

I think the problem is in the `focus` of the view, because I have tested whether the `TextView` has focus even after calling `imgPathTv.setSelected(true)`, and the result is it does not has the focus.

***Updated_Code***

```
String imgPath = dataBaseRow.getImgPath();
    if (imgPath.equals("")) {
        Log.d(TAG, "@createInfoReport(): dataBaseRow.getImgPath() Returns NULL");
        imgPathTv.setText("NULL");
    }else {
        Log.d(TAG, "@createInfoReport(): dataBaseRow.getImgPath() Has Value");

            imgPathTv.setSelected(true);
            imgPathTv.setText(imgPath);

            if(imgPathTv.findFocus() != null) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "there is a View has the Focus", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "NO View has the Focus", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Java_Code:

```
    TextView imgPathTv = (TextView) mDialog.findViewById(R.id.imgPathValue);
    Log.i(TAG, "@createInfoReport(): imgPathTv IS IN FOCUS");
    imgPathTv.setSelected(true);
```

TextView_xml:

```
<TextView 
                    android:id="@+id/imgPathValue"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:ellipsize="marquee"
                    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                    android:focusable="true"
                    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                    android:fadingEdge="horizontal"/>
```

Comment: @Opiatefuchs I checked that , but no, no doubled ids

Comment: @Opiatefuchs would you please take alook at the update?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your text length is not long enough to let the Marquee runs. In other words, the marquee only works when the text is away larger than its respective width/area. So, I recommend to try to set the `android:layout_width` to be, for an example, `200dp` or even more. then try the `marquee`. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not a answer for a solution, but have to show code. Does it work, if You set following parameters? I don´t think that cursorVisible is important for that, but maybe the scrollbars and focusableInTouchMode. I have tried it with this parameters and it worked.

```
android:scrollbars="horizontal"    
android:cursorVisible="false"   
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```