# Android TextView Marquee not working

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, marquee

**Marquee not working for my TextView Please check below code**

**XML Code** for  `TextView`

```
                          <TextView
                            android:id="@+id/mtextcash"
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                            android:ellipsize="marquee"
                            android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                            android:maxLength="5"
                            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                            android:scrollbars="horizontal"
                            android:singleLine="true"
                            android:text="Simple application that shows how to use marquee, with a long text"
                            android:textColor="@color/white"
                            android:textColorHint="@color/white"
                            android:textSize="25dp" />
```

**In Activity OnCreate**

```
TextView inputAvailableCash = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mtextcash);
inputAvailableCash.setSelected(true);
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: The issue is with your android:layout_width value which is wrap_content. check readyandroid  answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10458844/textview-marquee-doesnt-work?rq=1                       or          http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24165143/textview-with-marquee-is-not-working?rq=1

Answer (score 8):

Since the text is very long and and your code will only work if you write the text in single line. Either add

```
 android:singleline="true"
```

in xml or change your java code to.

```
  TextView inputAvailableCash = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mtextcash);
        inputAvailableCash.setSelected(true);
         inputAvailableCash.setSingleLine(true);
```

This will surely work for you.

Comment: I had `maxLines="1"` but it turned out it's not enough. `singleline="true" ` made it work! 10x.

Comment: I realised that the marquee effect only started its animation when I touched it, so I looked and found your answer. In Kotlin is `inputAvailableCash.isSelected = true`. Is that possible by typing it in the layout/XML?

Answer (score 4):

Once try by putting these params to your TextView - It works

```
android:singleLine="true"
android:ellipsize="marquee"
android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
android:scrollHorizontally="true"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

And you also need to setSelected(true):

```
 my_TextView.setSelected(true);
```

Answer (score 3):

The minimum code to run marquee on `TextView` is

```
<TextView
    .
    .
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:ellipsize="marquee"
    android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
    />
```

also do not forget to set selected as below

```
textview.setSelected(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

add this attribute in the xml file

```
android:focusable="true"    
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
```

Answer (score 1):

For marquee effect width should be "match_parent" or static(like 200dp...etc) always. And programatically make it setSelected true as you already done then just make it's width as match_parent in xml it will work.

Edited xml:

```
                     <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/mtextcash"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                        android:ellipsize="marquee"
                        android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                        android:maxLength="5"
                        android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                        android:scrollbars="horizontal"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:text="Simple application that shows how to use marquee, with a long text"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="25dp" />
```

If by doing match_parent it will effect at your design then you have to manage for it by fixing it's width or with some other way.

As per your xml code you are using android:maxLength="5" means only 5 character will be entered so you can fix it's width by 50dp or any other static size.

Comment: thanks i have tried it i just forget to remove android:maxLength="5" because of that its not working.

Answer (score 1):

Hey check this code but marquee working when your text size i.e length is longer.its working at my side.:)

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mywidget"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textColor="#2086CA"
        android:text="Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
```

Hope this helps.:)

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/mtextcash"
                   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                   android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                   android:ellipsize="marquee"
                   android:gravity="center"
                   android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
                   android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                   android:singleLine="true"
                   android:text="Simple application that shows how to use marquee, with a long text"
                   android:textColor="@color/white"
                   android:textColorHint="@color/white"
                   android:textSize="25dp" />
```

Comment: also need to add `setSelected(true)` in `onCreate` method of java file